# What does からかっちゃ mean?

Tags: manga, parsing

I found the following dialogue in a manga.

[image]

> 繋がれてる【つながれてる】からって
>
> **からかっちゃ**ダメですって

My thinking is that the person speaking is describing what the dog is "saying", i.e. "I'm tied to this pole! Dont' **???**"

Where the **???** is the meaning of the word/phrase からかっちゃ which I don't know how to parse. My only guess so far was that it is a contraction, からかっちゃ = からかっては.

Looking for more occurrences of the phrase I found that it might be a catchphrase of sorts of another manga character, but that didn't help me grasp the meaning.

[image]

Comment: Actually I just came across the verb からかう, "to ridicule; to mock" that I must have missed before - could that be it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct.  からかっちゃ is a contraction of からかっては, where からかう is the verb you came across in your comment.  Although it is probably better translated here as "tease" or "harass".

So speaking about the dog,

> 繋がれてるからってからかっちゃダメですって　→　Just because he's tied/chained up doesn't mean you can tease the dog!